# laptop stuck at advance options when booted and no drives are shown in cmd

Tags: windows, windows-10

when I start my laptop, it stucks at blank screen for a while and then it shows 2 options, advance options and turm of computer. I searched a bit and found a way to see if my drives are still there or not. When I opened notepad through cmd, and selected to open file, I can not see my drives there (C and D). I can see only two drives:

1. Boot(X:) and 2. CD Drive (D:)

I do not want to lose my data. I tried the 3 options of advanced options, system restore, system image recovery and startup repair. But none of them worked. My laptop is Asus R541UJ.

It all started when yesterday a BSOD appeared with error CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED. then it tried to restart the system but it could not, this problem occurred. One more thing my D drive used to be of 510GB, and through cmd and notepad the new Boot(X:) drive is of 510GB from which, 508GB is not used, whereas, as D drive was filled by 450GB. So please help me with it and tell me what to do, I do not want to lose my data. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Drive X: is a virtual drive. It exists only in Repair Mode.

Maybe your hard disk has failed. If it is not visible in the BIOS.

While in Repair Mode, you can do this to find out more about your disk:

Run this command: diskpart.exe
Type these subcommands:

```
select disk 0
detail disk
exit
```

If you see no partitions (i.e. 'no volums found') then you might have to format or replace the disk, then restore your data from your external backup medium.